# Problem in output of Origin Destination Matrix Analyst in arcpy python3

Tags: python-3.x, arcpy, network-analysis

I have written a program about OD matrix Analyst (Network analyst) using arcpy (Python3 and ArcGIS Pro), but I got some problems, the code did not get the defined data as origin and it just get a same data as destination and origin, although I defined a different data for both. The result would be between the same origin and destination. It does not get properly origin data using arcpy.GetParameterAsText, but it gets destination data properly from previous process (inDestinations). 
The second problem is: I do not have access to the name of created dataset (ODCostMatrix1\ODLines1) in geodatabase due to change. Because I want to use the output of created dataset for the next process and whenever I run the program, the name of it will changed automatic (ODCostMatrix2\ODLines2). If I import output of OD Matrix as a saved layer file to the code, how can I access to the created line from analyst network for the next process?

Any help would be appericiated, thanks in advance.

```
#  generate Tesselation
import arcpy
#Check out the Network Analyst extension license
arcpy.CheckOutExtension("Network")
# set workspace 
gdb = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0)
# set basic setting
arcpy.env.workspace = gdb
arcpy.env.overwriteOutput  = True
output_tesselation = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(2)
output_feature = gdb + "\\" + output_tesselation
extent = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(3)
shpae_type = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(4)
area = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(5)

arcpy.GenerateTessellation_management(output_feature, extent, shpae_type, area)
arcpy.AddMessage("Tesselation was generated successfully.")


# 2. calculate centroid of each tesselation--------------------------------------

# calculate centroid of x and y for polygons of tessalation
arcpy.AddField_management(output_feature, "Longitude", "DOUBLE")
arcpy.AddField_management(output_feature, "Latitude", "DOUBLE")
arcpy.CalculateField_management(output_feature, "Longitude", "!SHAPE.CENTROID.X!", "PYTHON3")
arcpy.CalculateField_management(output_feature, "Latitude", "!SHAPE.CENTROID.Y!", "PYTHON3")

# convert table to table process: table of tesselation to new table
new_table = arcpy.TableToTable_conversion(output_feature, gdb , "new_table")

# convert created table to x and y points
centroid_tesselation_point = arcpy.management.XYTableToPoint(new_table, gdb + "\\" + "centroid_tesselation_point", "Longitude", "Latitude", "", arcpy.SpatialReference(3857))
arcpy.AddMessage("The centroid points of tesselation was created.")


# 3. calculate reach time of each employee to each centroid of tesselations------

#Set local variables
inNetworkDataset = "S:\\GIS\\Stammdaten\\Network_Dataset_20190924.gdb\\ND\\ND_20190924"
outNALayerName = "WorkerTONewOfficeDrivetimeMatrix"
impedanceAttribute = "Time_Car"        # Time_Car , Time_Walk , Length

inOrgins = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(1)
inDestinations = gdb + "\\" + "centroid_tesselation_point"
outLayerFile = "C:\\Users\\somaye.fazeli\\ArcGisProject_Test\\" + outNALayerName

#Create a new OD Cost matrix layer
outNALayer = arcpy.na.MakeODCostMatrixLayer(inNetworkDataset, outNALayerName, impedanceAttribute)

#Get the layer object from the result object. The OD cost matrix layer can 
#now be referenced using the layer object.
outNALayer = outNALayer.getOutput(0)

#Get the names of all the sublayers within the OD cost matrix layer.
subLayerNames = arcpy.na.GetNAClassNames(outNALayer)

#Stores the layer names that we will use later
originsLayerName = subLayerNames["Origins"]
destinationsLayerName = subLayerNames["Destinations"]

#Load the warehouse locations as origins using a default field mappings and
#a search tolerance of 1000 Meters.
arcpy.na.AddLocations(outNALayer, originsLayerName, inOrgins)
arcpy.AddMessage("Origin data was imported.")


arcpy.na.AddLocations(outNALayer, destinationsLayerName, inDestinations)
arcpy.AddMessage("Destination data was imported.")

#Solve the OD cost matrix layer
arcpy.na.Solve(outNALayer)

#Save the solved OD cost matrix layer as a layer file on disk with relative path
arcpy.SaveToLayerFile_management(outNALayer, outLayerFile, "ABSOLUTE")

arcpy.AddMessage("Newtork Analysis completed successfully")

# calculate average time of each destinaiton
input_layer = gdb + "\\ODCostMatrix1\\ODLines1"
arcpy.Statistics_analysis(input_layer, gdb + "\\" + "Mean_Drive_Time", [["Total_Time_Car", "MEAN"]], "DestinationID")
```

Comment: sorry, I wrote wrong in the code. the right value for destination variable is :inDestinations = centroid_tesselation_point

Comment: You may want to post this in gis.stackexchange.com.